# How to check String values equal null?

Tags: java, string

I'm new in java programming. Now I have a problem when I have String variable equals to null. When I check condition on that String it error :

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*.

This is my code :

```
public class Test {
    static String a=null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(a.equals(null)){
            System.out.println("Null");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `a.equals(null)` you should be doing `a == null`.

```
if(a == null) {
    System.out.println("Null");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `StringUtils` to check if String is `null` or empty by doing:

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(a)) {
    System.out.println("Null");
}
```

Comment: Why i cannot use equals() method?

Comment: Because if `a` itself is `null`, it will be `null.equals()` and it does not hold good. You can't invoke a method on a `null` object.

Comment: @user2004685: Well, on a `null` *reference*. There's no such thing as a `null` object. It's worth keeping the distinction between variables, references and objects very clear.

Comment: @user2004685 i cannot use StringUtils.isEmpty() method. why?

Comment: @Huo Chhunleng, you need to add org.apache.commons.lang3 dependency to your project. If you are using maven, then choose it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you are right. It should have been `null` reference and not object. @WeGa Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Check with == or != 
like:

```
if(a!=null){
    System.out.println("is not Null");
}
```

Comment: Why i cannot use equals() method?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gkcrg/index.html

Comment: Better in practice , Instead of using If(a!= null) you should use if(null!=a)

Comment: @ManthanB: No, that's a terrible idea: a) it's no safer; b) it's less readable. These "Yoda conditions" may make sense in *some* languages where the type of the condition in an `if` statement doesn't have to be a Boolean type, but it makes no sense in Java for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet for the comment.

Comment: It's not "better" to reverse the comparison, 'null != a' vs. 'a != null', because both expressions are exactly equivalent. Equality and inequality are symmetric. If anything, the reversed expression is worse, because everyone recognizes it as reversed, which slows down mental processing of the construct. There is no "practice" to the reversal; it just makes code look worse.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a potential for both references to be `null`, you can use

```
Objects.equals(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for null

```
if(a == null){
  System.out.println("I am null");
}
```

If you want to check for empty or blank String

```
if(a != null && a.length() == 0){
  System.out.println("I am an empty String");
}
```